# How to draw my polygon with Angular Google Map?

Tags: angular, google-maps, agm

I'm using on my angular project this version of Angular Google Maps "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.2" . My concern is about how to re-draw the polygon I have drawn on my google Map, I'm storing the latitude and
longitude, How can I redraw my polygon ?

[image]

```
    <agm-map [latitude]="latitudeMapUpdate"
        [longitude]="longitudeMapUpdate"
        [disableDefaultUI]="false"
        [zoom]="13"
        (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)">
    </agm-map>

    onMapReady(map) {
        this.initDrawingManager(map);
    }

    initDrawingManager(map: any) {
        const self = this;
        const options = {
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
                drawingModes: ["polygon"]
            },
            polygonOptions: {
                draggable: true,
                editable: true
            },
            drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
        };
        const drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager(options);
        drawingManager.setMap(map);
        google.maps.event.addListener(
            drawingManager,
            'overlaycomplete',
            (event) => {
                alert(event.overlay.getPath().getArray());
                const paths =  event.overlay.getPaths();
                
                drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
                self.updatePointList(event.overlay.getPath());
                const newShape = event.overlay;
                newShape.type = event.type;
                google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', () => {
                    this.setSelectionPolygons(newShape)
                });
                this.setSelectionPolygons(newShape)
            });
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', this.clearSelection);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', this.clearSelection);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-map-button'), 'click', this.deleteSelectedShape);
        console.log({map});
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on 3rd party libraries/modules to implement the map for you, you can load the script directly so that you can use the google map's official documentations like this [simple polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple#maps_polygon_simple-typescript) sample. To do this, simply load the JS map script in the index.html.

Here is a working sample for your reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-map-64456023

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
<my-app>loading</my-app>
```

**style.css**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.map {
  height:100%;
}
```

**simple-map.component.html**

```
<div #map class="map"></div>
```

**simple-map.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
declare const google: any;

@Component({
  selector: "my-maps",
  templateUrl: "./simple-map.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./simple-map.component.css"]
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("map", { static: true }) mapElement: any;
  map: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const mapProperties = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.886, -70.268),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(
      this.mapElement.nativeElement,
      mapProperties
    );
    // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
    const triangleCoords = [
      { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 },
      { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
      { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
      { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 }
    ];
    // Construct the polygon.
    const bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: triangleCoords,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#FF0000",
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    bermudaTriangle.setMap(this.map);
  }
}
```

Comment: After entering my key, I'm getting "ERROR
Error: google is not defined"

Comment: That's actually an issue with Stackblitz, to fix this, just put a space in any part of the code (i.e. in simple-map.component.ts)